# What is the differnce between a software framework and a software platform?

Tags: java, .net, frameworks, platform

I have seen the use of the word "platform" and the word "framework" used interchangeably. I would like to get some input on the subject. If someone could answer these questions, it might clear it up for me...

1. Is .NET a framework or platform?
2. From the product side, would Visual Studio be considered a Platform?
3. What would JavaScript be considered?

I am confused. :)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is your question about Java or Javascript? (they are not the same thing)

Comment: Nope, more about how to define a platform vs a framework. I THINK that Java would be considered a framework rather than a platform...

Comment: @Sean Java is most definitely not a framework. It's a platform since it contains an execution environment, a programming language and middleware.

Comment: So do you want to remove your question about JavaScript as it is just a language.

Comment: @Kayaman But so does .NET, and people insist on calling that a framework including Microsoft :/

Comment: Well, Microsoft also calls IIS a production grade server.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that a platform is something you build on top of -- your OS, an ORM or a set of services provided by an API.

A framework is something you use to build up inside of -- think ASP.Net, WCF or .Net itself.

The platform has functionality which you are extending, while by itself the framework does nothing until you utilize it to create an app.

Answer (score 0):

1. .NET is a Microsoft Framework
2. Visual Studio is an IDE
3. JavaScript is a programming language

A platform IMO is a system, a kind of environment, can consist of a number of different frameworks working together. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform
Framework is a toolkit to help you get things done quicker and with conventions so everyone is on the same page.

Comment: Alex, so you feel the platform is where the product/service would be consumed? For instance, the platform for ESPN.com could be considered "Web". The ESPN app platform would be considered Andriod, iPhone and Windows Phone, etc.??

Comment: Yes,  that's how I understand it. But also can be consumed as a dev platform. You'll probably get different opinions but that's my take.

Answer (score 0):

I can simplify you a little things: 
we can say that Windows OS is a "platefom" but about. Net is a "framework"

Generally:

- Framework is a set of components that are used to create foundations, architecture and outline for a software.
- A platform is formed by the assembly equipment such as a PC and an operating system.

Comment: So to clarify, if I am open an application to physically writing code for an iPhone, I am using a tool or product. I will code in a framework (not sure what that is for iPhone) and the platform would be iOS (same for iPad and iPhone), correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that we can say that if you want :)